# Sound keeps repeating (stuttering)

Tags: 13.10, pulseaudio

Yesterday while I was watching a YouTube video the sound started glitching. There are two kinds of glitches:

1. The most common kind is where the sound repeats an approximately 1/4 second bit of sound for around two seconds, then plays normally (beginning from where it would have been had it not been repeating) for another two seconds. Then it repeats *ad nauseum*.
2. Occasionally, it the sound will repeatedly pause for a fraction of a second. This isn't so annoying as I don't miss any content. This second option seems to only occur when playback is started while CPU usage is low. However, low CPU doesn't guarantee this option.

I originally blamed Adobe Flash. However, killing it didn't fix anything. Then I noticed that PulseAudio was consuming a lot of audio during the glitches. So, I killed it. No dice. I rebooted. No dice. I decided to test another program, so I tried Rhythmbox. The same problem occurred, but with less frequency.

What's going on here?

Partial output from `lshw`:

```
*-multimedia
    description: Audio device
    product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1b
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
    version: 03
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
    resources: irq:48 memory:fe020000-fe023fff
```